# Is it possible to skip update when all tests failed when using mybatis with <set>?

Tags: java, mybatis

While using mybatis, dynamic SQL is very powerful, for example for an UPDATE:

```
<update id="update">
  UPDATE BOOKS
  <set>
    <if test="book.author != null">AUTHOR=#{book.author},</if>
    <if test="book.name != null">NAME=#{book.name}</if>
  </set>
  WHERE ID=#{book.id}
</update>
```

This works when author or name is not null, it failed when both null, because the SQL has syntax error.

My question: is it possible to skip the update when all tests between `<set>` failed, or I have to write extra java code to check before executing the `update` statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Skipping statement execution using XML element is not possible.

If you just want to avoid writing Java conditions, however, including `ID` in the `SET` clause might be sufficient.

```xml
UPDATE BOOKS
SET
  ID = #{book.id}
  <if test="book.author != null">, AUTHOR=#{book.author}</if>
  <if test="book.name != null">, NAME=#{book.name}</if>
WHERE ID = #{book.id}
```